# Porque ocorre perda de pontos de reputação sem justificativa?

Tags: suporte, reputação

Estive olhando hoje pela manhã meu perfil e notei algo estranho na aba *Reputação.* Aparentemente sem lógica em alguns dias aparecem pontos negativos. Quando é aberto o dia para ver aparece que não houve alterações. Quando votei contra apareceu o -1, que é normal.

Exemplo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma explicação?

Comment: Você recebe -1 quando da uma donwvote em alguma resposta.

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas se você recebe um voto em uma pergunta, você receberá 5 pontos, mas se esse voto for retirado em um dia diferente, será descontado essa quantia, pois ela já foi contabilizada na reputação. Não sei se ficaria explícito o motivo neste caso.

Comment: Não é sem justificativa! A justificativa está aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Sobre o votedown eu sei, pq aparece ali. Mas o -4 aparece que não houve alterações. Se fosse por downvote não deveria aparecer as perguntas?

Comment: Olhei no meu histórico e todos os votos contra, sem exceção, estão especificados. Até mesmos os dias em que a reputação totalizou 0 há especificado os pontos ganhos e perdidos. Eu realmente acho que foi o que citei acima, sobre terem retirado um *up vote* de uma pergunta sua e junto alguma pergunta/comentário que você votou contra ser removido (especulação minha).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss vc que tem mais de 10k de rep não consegue ver a alteração de reputação do Diego no dia 08/04? Pois eu vejo que teve uma pergunta removida nesse dia que ele perdeu 2 pontos que ele ganhou em uma sugestão de edição

Comment: @Math para mim aparece igual para ele dizendo que não houve alterações.

Answer (score 9):

Ótima pergunta. Investigando a sua reputação eu sai com mais dúvidas do que quando comecei.

A aba de reputação pode ser algo bem confuso por envolver privilégios de ver perguntas removidas, questões do sigilo do voto negativo e outras coisas que eu não faço nem ideia do que podem ser (desculpa se desapontei).

Olhando um determinado período da sua aba de reputação pela minha conta que vejo isso:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já olhando o mesmo período sem estar logado eu vejo isso:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na maioria dos casos você perdeu pontos que foram reversões de sugestões de edições aprovadas que haviam lhe rendido dois pontos no momento da aprovação e em algum outro momento a publicação foi removida e os pontos descontados, como por exemplo a variação do dia 08/04 nessa questão: [500 Internal Server Error - value assigned to parameter REPORT_SCRIPTLET - IReport 1.3.3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122087/3117)

Agora, por que tem por exemplo um +1 nos dias 29/03 e 23/02 que só eu vejo e ainda assim sem nenhuma explicação é algo difícil de entender, e também por que não apareceu para você as variações de reputação que eu vejo nos dias 01/04, 18/03, 11/03, 04/03, dentre outros.

Eu sei que minha resposta responde apenas parcialmente a sua dúvida, mas achei que era melhor do que nada ;-)

Comment: Isso é um problema que já ocorreu comigo, eu tenho privilegio pra ver removidas, e não aparece pra mim também, mesmo que o afetado seja eu proprio. Acho essas limitações do sistema muito tolas, ora, se eu tenho a droga do privilegio pra ver o que foi removido, porque me censurar de ver a origem de rep perdida em posts removidos? Não faz sentido algum isso.

Comment: @Math ótima resposta.

Comment: Como tem acesso a essas informações dos votos? Isso não era para ser sigiloso mesmo entre moderadores? Tentei com a minha conta e não tenho essa opção. @Math

Comment: @DanielOmine não entendi, de qual informação dos votos você está se referindo?

Comment: essas imagens ué... rsrs

Comment: @DanielOmine vc pode ver nesse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/17091/diego?tab=reputation

Comment: no tablet android aparece a tab mas no pc não.